# Movie where a boy is assumed to be a Nazi

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't have much to go on with details here.

English movie. Anytime from the 2000's, give or take some time from the late 90's ('98, 99) till about 2008?
Anyway, I'm sure the parts in question where part of a sub-plot.

There is a family of which either parent is re-married or in a new relationship. I'm going with the mother of the boy sees or is with a new man. White actors all of them.
The boy must be in his teens, as he is still in school and going through what the parents assume is teenage drama.

Eventually, at some point in the film, the boy dyes his hair blonde. He keeps a beanie on (skull cap) to hide the hair colour. But he is eventually outed by the father at dinner one night(?)

It is revealed that he is in fact in a stage production of The Sounds of Music, wherein he plays one of the Nazi soldiers. The family then make an effort to see the play.

I recall the father or mother following him around and catching him outside a building with some other boys that also have dyed blonde hair. The building was the rehearsal stage.

As for the rest of the movie, I can't quite recall the main plots or actors. It might be that this was the main plot.

As I said, English speaking movie. Was set in either America or England. White actors. Sorry, but I don't have much else to go with here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Pacifier (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395699/)

> The school's vice principal, Duane Murney, informs Wolfe that **Seth has cut and bleached his hair**, has a **Nazi armband** in his locker, and has skipped every wrestling practice for a month. At home, Seth tells Wolfe he only joined the wrestling team because of his father. After Seth sneaks out of the house, Wolfe leaves Zoe in charge and follows him to the town theater, where he learns that Seth has **secretly joined an amateur production of The Sound of Music**.
>   <sup><sub>- Plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pacifier#Plot)</sub></sup>

[image]

Comment: thanks to both of you. hectic that it was in this movie, not that i tend to remember much from comedies anyway :)

Comment: I remembered this Nazi/Sound of Music subplot and reveal, but did not connect it to Vin Diesel or his Pacifier film until I did some Google-fu.

Comment: Google-fu. gonna use that term from now on

Answer (score 4):

You're searching for [The Pacifier](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395699/). The blond [kid](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0014993/?ref_=tt_cl_t5) joins a play and is assumed to be a nazi. He tries to hide the fact hat he's in a play because it is not a 'boy thing'.